# conditional deep merge an array of hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, merge, nested

I have two data structures that I would like to merge together - as I understand this is called a 'deep merge'.

It should follow the same logic as Rails' [deep merge](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge), except my requirement differs in that values are only overwritten on the target hash if they match certain conditions.

As an example, given the following two data structures:

```
hash1 = { 
  "data": [ 
    {"id": "1", "type": "foo", created_at: "<IGNORE>" }, 
    {"id": "2", "type": "bar", created_at: "<IGNORE>" } 
  ], 
  meta: { 
    page: 1 
  } 
}  

hash2 = { 
  "data": [ 
    {"id": "1", "type": "baz", created_at: "01.01.2022", name: 'thing' }, 
    {"id": "2", "type": "qux", created_at: "02.01.2022" } 
  ], 
  meta: { 
    page: 1 
  } 
}
```

I would like to achieve the following output:

```
irb(main):001:0> hash1.deep_merge(hash2)
=> { 
     "data": [ 
       {"id": "1", "type": "baz", created_at: "<IGNORE>", name: 'thing' }, 
       {"id": "2", "type": "qux", created_at: "<IGNORE>" } 
     ], 
     meta: { 
       page: 1 
     } 
   }
```

In hash1, the values for `created_at` contain a tag `<IGNORE>` that should stipulate that the corresponding value from hash2 should not be merged. All the other keys and values should merge as it would if I was to use Rails' `deep_merge`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland , understood. I have updated with what I hope is a more satisfactory statement in words.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: You didn't say what the conditions are, even so I'll help you transform this input into this output, it would be interesting to edit your question later and say the conditions.

i don't have many knowledge in ruby but i created a simple algorithm for merge two hash structures without duplicates and keep data type of key, it's not
the  better algorithm or solution but i think this implemetation help to your a find other better solution for resolver your problem

Complexity O(n)

Join the hashes and transform the keys into a string

`result = hash1.merge(hash2).transform_keys(&:to_s)`

save meta information

`meta = hash1[:meta]`

convert array of symbols to array of strings

```
`result = result["data"].map do |res|
   {
     'id' => res[:id].to_s,
     'type' => res[:type].to_s,
     'created_at' => res[:created_at].to_s,
     'name' => res[:name].to_s
    }
  end
`
```

if the hash does not have the key name remove it

```
`
result =  
  result.map { 
    |res| res["name" == ""] ? {
      'id' => res["id"],
      'type' => res["type"],
      'created_at' => res["created_at"]
    } : res
  }
`
```

Build new hash :D

`final_result  = {"data" => result, meta: meta}`

[output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi1Bj.png)